# How to Highlight an Object in beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I **beforeShowDay** highlight the values in an Object?

1. jquery datepicker

```js
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var date = $("#calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  }).val();
  var date = highdate;
  console.log(highdate);
  console.log(hightext);
  var Highlight = highdate[date];
  var HighlighText = hightext[date];
  if (Highlight) {
    return [true, "Highlighted", HighlighText];
  } else {
    return [true, '', ''];
  }
}
```

2.highdate Objects

```
Object
0:"2018-04-04"
1:"2018-04-30"
__proto__:Object
```

3.hightext Objects

```
Object
0:"text1"
1:"text2"
__proto__:Object
```

4.css

```css
.Highlighted a {
  background-color: Green !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: White !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What does not work yet?

Comment: I want to show a green mark on the day of highdate@ datepicker

Comment: Ahd what happens with the current code?